# How to assign sub-object to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object that looks like

```
var obj = {
    p1: {
        name: "name1",
        age: "age1"
    }
    p2: {
        name: "name2",
        age: "age2"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access name and age iteratively, meaning something like this:

```
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        func1(p.name);
        func2(p.age);
    }
}
```

However, p.name is shown as "undefined" in debugger, so are the other keys of p. I wonder if javascript allows users to assign sub-object to a new variable like in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing something there. Look:

```
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        func1(obj[p].name);
        func2(obj[p].age);
    }
}
```

This should work.

`p` only exists as a property of `obj` so, even inside a `for-in` loop, you still have to access `p` as a property of `obj` (from the loop).

If you're learning javascript, this may not be obvious but there's actually two ways to access object properties: dot notation and the square brackets notation. Using your example, `obj.p1.name === obj['p1']['name]`.

Sometimes you need square brackets notation because you want to pass it some variable, which is what you need inside the `for-in` loop.

I hope this is clear. If not, you can see it working on this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rekogir/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Your nested object is strictly formatted (has name, age in all nested elements).
Also what's the reason to check that it `hasOwnProperty`? 
You iterate an object by keys and don't know it has `iterator key`?
Why not just simply iterate the object?

```js
var obj = {
    p1: {
        name: "name1",
        age: "age1"
    },
    p2: {
        name: "name2",
        age: "age2"
    }
};

function func1(value) {
  console.log('Name:', value);  
}

function func2(value) {
  console.log('Age:', value);  
}

for(var i in obj) {
  if(typeof obj[i] != 'object')
    continue;
  console.log('\nOutputing:', i);
  func1(obj[i].name);  
  func2(obj[i].age);
}
```

Comment: It works. Could you please explain why `obj[i].name` not `obj.i.name`?

Comment: Because of it's syntax construction.

Comment: When You do without [] it cannot pas i as variable that is key to select.

Comment: In for loop i is key (string) of object that represented as variable when You do obj.i.name js interpreter thinks that You want to get i element of object. But really is that You want to get not i but key that kept in i. It's like i='p1'; so it means: obj[i].name == obj['p1'].name == obj.p1.name

Comment: Cuz in JS for(i in obj) is not like foreach in php, in js i is key to element, not object itself, but in ES6 foreach analogue is for(i of obj) {console.log(i.name);} cannot wait when es6 will be standard in browsers

Comment: P.s. read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in